# Tabula - py ignores NaN values and shifts table cell values into the wrong column

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, tabula, tabula-py

So I was experimenting a little bit with tabula for Python and had a strange exception.
The first Column of the table always stretches over 4 rows. So for the first 4 cells, witch are stretched over multiple rows, tabula just asumes NaN for the the following 3 rows of the streched cell.
But in the last streched cell, tabula just shifts the values of the next column into the NaN position.
I can probably work around this, but is there a fast fix, maybe some parameter or argument for tabula, which might fix this behavior?

The PDF Table looks like this:
[image: table of the PDF]

My code:

```
 import tabula

 df = tabula.read_pdf('file.pdf', pages='all', pandas_options={'header': None} ,lattice = True)
 print(df)
```

My output:

```
             0                       1                       2          3   4
0       Montag               1./2.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
1          NaN               3./4.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
2          NaN               5./6.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
3          NaN               7./8.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
4     Dienstag               1./2.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
5          NaN               3./4.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
6          NaN               5./6.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
7          NaN               7./8.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
8     Mittwoch               1./2.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
9          NaN               3./4.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
10         NaN               5./6.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
11         NaN               7./8.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
12  Donnerstag               1./2.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
13         NaN               3./4.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
14         NaN               5./6.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
15         NaN               7./8.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
16     Freitag               1./2.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung  Budrowitz NaN
17   3./4.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung               Budrowitz        NaN NaN
18   5./6.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung               Budrowitz        NaN NaN
19   7./8.\rUE  Projekt - Realisierung               Budrowitz        NaN NaN
```

I tried googling for some arguments (already found header = none,lattice, guess and stream) but nothing really adresses or fixes the problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem.   Did you find a solution?

Comment: @user3761340 sadly not. As the table is always the same I just hardcoded around the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass pandas_options to tabula.read_pdf like the following:

`pandas_options={'keep_default_na': False, 'na_values':['nan']}`